# JavaScript to search a string and brace all capitalzied tokens

Tags: javascript, regex

I need JavaScript to search a string for all capitalized tokens, excluding the first, and replace all of the them with a bracketed token.

E.g.

```js
"Rose Harbor in Bloom: A Novel" -> "Rose {Harbor} in {Bloom}: {A} {Novel}"
"In America: a novel" -> "In {America}: a novel"
"What else. In the country" -> "What else. {In} the country"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use a matched string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) in the replacements using $&.
Also, `\b` specifies a word boundary and `[A-Z]` will specify all capital characters.
`*?` attempts to make a match with as few characters as possible

So you want `.replace(/\b[A-Z].*?\b/g, '{$&}')`

So as an example:

```js
"a String is Good yes?".replace(/\b[A-Z].*?\b/g, '{$&}')
```

returns

```js
"a {String} is {Good} yes?"
```

---

To `exclude the first token` you'll have to get a little creative;

```js
function surroundCaps(str) {
    //get first word
    var temp = str.match(/^.+?\b/);
    //if word was found
    if (temp) {
        temp = temp[0];
        //remove it from the string
        str = str.substring(temp.length);
    }
    else
        temp = '';

    str = str.replace(/\b[A-Z].*?\b/g, '{$&}');
    return temp + str;
}

surroundCaps('String is Good Yes'); //'String is {Good} {Yes}'
```